# Test Case always fail because can't find element locator

Tags: selenium, robotframework, keyword

I have created this Keyword:

```
Validate Header 
Wait Until Page Contains     id=outputtext-text-Header:ApplicationHeaderCoachView1:ApplicationHeaderCoachViewInner1:Output_Text1
Element Should Be Visible    id=outputtext-text-Header:ApplicationHeaderCoachView1:ApplicationHeaderCoachViewInner1:Output_Text1
```

But it always fail and give me this error:

```
Text 'id=outputtext-text-Header:ApplicationHeaderCoachView1:ApplicationHeaderCoachViewInner1:Output_Text1' did not appear in 5 seconds.
```

The Element HTML Code is:

```
<p id="outputtext-text-Header:ApplicationHeaderCoachView1:ApplicationHeaderCoachViewInner1:Output_Text1" aria-labelledby="outputtext-label-Header:ApplicationHeaderCoachView1:ApplicationHeaderCoachViewInner1:Output_Text1" class="text-left">FCP</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're waiting for the page to contain the literal string "id=outputtext-text..." displayed somewhere on the screen. Are you sure that's what should appear on the page? It looks like a locator, but that keyword takes a string instead of a locator.

I don't know for sure what you're trying to do, but if you're waiting for an element with the given id, you should use [Wait until page contains element](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Wait%20Until%20Page%20Contains%20Element) which takes a locator as an argument.

Comment: Thanks @Bryan Oakley. What I'm trying to do is only verify that element is present on the page. I don't care about the text that this element display, I only need to verify its filled on the page. But always have this error that element that element did not appear in 5 seconds.

Comment: @CarlosPeixoto Have you tried 10 seconds? 20 seconds? 30 seconds? Have the element really visible on the page during the test run?